# Twilio Programmable Chat - How to logout user?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have implemented twilio programmable chat SDK. My problem is to figure out how to go ahead and log that user out. Since we are on a ionic application we need a proper logout from twilio else the messages might persist for the other user as well. Can some one show some light on the same.

Comment: What do you mean by a proper logout? Twilio Chat doesn't persist messages for you. When you authorize a user to use Twilio Chat with the access token, they can only access messages in channels they belong to or can join.